# Is there a way of tracking stages

Tags: javafx, focus, scene, stage

I want to track focused node to perform some action after user inactivity on that node. But focused for my application means that there could be only 1 focus node in the entire application (application has numerous Stages and they creation are out of my control. I also cannot force different department of my company to use registry to register stages after they create them).

E.g. I have a property for focused component scene.focusOwnerProperty(), I can track whether Stage is stage.focusedProperty() but I'm searching the way to retrieve all stages.

Do you know the way?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. `com.sun.javafx.stage.StageHelper.getStages()` list all stages.

Comment: But note that `StageHelper` is not part of the public API, so there is no guarantee this solution will continue to work in future versions of JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `Window[] windows = Window.getWindows();` this is part of the Public Api and works fine for me.

Comment: I can't find a `Window.getWindows()` api in the [JavaFX 8 Window javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html).

Comment: Oh my bad. Eclipse imported the awt Window class. In FX you can use Window.impl_getWindows(). But that is no public api..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for answers. I write a class which provides an easy way to track currently focused Node and "focused" Scene. "Focused" means the focused component from focused Stage. If there are any mistakes in my code I would be grateful for if you notice and inform me.

```
    import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
    import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
    import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
    import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    import com.sun.javafx.stage.StageHelper;

    /**
     * Tracks focused component among all {@link Stage}'s. Currently this is singleton but it will make service
     * out of it.
     *
     * @author created: kszymanek on 8 sty 2016 15:19:32
     */
    public class GlobalFocusTracker
    {
        private static final GlobalFocusTracker INSTANCE = new GlobalFocusTracker();
        /**
         * tracks stage list and each stage and registers {@link #sceneListener} on
         * the focused stage
         */
        private StagesListener stagesListener;
        /**
         * tracks scene of the focused stage and registers
         * {@link #focusOwnerListener} on it
         */
        private SceneListener sceneListener;
        private FocusOwnerListener focusOwnerListener;
        private ReadOnlyObjectWrapper focusedNodeProperty = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper();
        private ReadOnlyObjectWrapper focusedSceneProperty = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper();

        private GlobalFocusTracker()
        {
        }

        public static GlobalFocusTracker getInstance()
        {
            return INSTANCE;
        }

        /**
         * @return current {@link Scene} from the currently focused {@link Stage}
         */
        public ReadOnlyObjectProperty focusedSceneProperty()
        {
            init();
            return focusedSceneProperty.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        /**
         * @return focused node among all stages. There could be one focus owner at
         *         the time. If end user focuses some other application there would
         *         be no focus node.
         */
        public ReadOnlyObjectProperty focusedNodeProperty()
        {
            init();
            return focusedNodeProperty.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        private void init()
        {
            if(stagesListener == null)
            {
                stagesListener = new StagesListener();
                sceneListener = new SceneListener();
                focusOwnerListener = new FocusOwnerListener();
                stagesListener.register();
            }
        }

        private class StagesListener implements ListChangeListener, ChangeListener
        {
            private ObservableList stages;

            @Override
            public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change aChange)
            {
                while(aChange.next())
                {
                    if(aChange.wasRemoved())
                    {
                        for(Stage stage : aChange.getRemoved())
                        {
                            stage.focusedProperty().removeListener(this);
                        }
                    }
                    if(aChange.wasAdded())
                    {
                        for(Stage stage : aChange.getAddedSubList())
                        {
                            stage.focusedProperty().addListener(this);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue aObservable, Boolean aOld, Boolean aNew)
            {
                Stage focusedStage = null;
                for(Stage stage : stages)
                {
                    if(stage.isFocused())
                    {
                        focusedStage = stage;
                    }
                }
                sceneListener.register(focusedStage);
            }

            public void register()
            {
                if(stages == null)
                {
                    stages = StageHelper.getStages();
                    stages.addListener(this);
                    for(Stage stage : stages)
                    {
                        stage.focusedProperty().addListener(this);
                        if(stage.isFocused())
                        {
                            sceneListener.register(stage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private class SceneListener implements ChangeListener
        {
            private Stage stage;

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue aObservable, Scene aOld, Scene aNew)
            {
                focusOwnerListener.register(aNew);
            }

            /**
             * @param aStage is {@code null} protected
             */
            public void register(Stage aStage)
            {
                if(aStage != stage)
                {
                    unregister();
                    stage = aStage;
                    if(aStage != null)
                    {
                        aStage.sceneProperty().addListener(this);
                        focusOwnerListener.register(aStage.getScene());
                    }
                }
            }

            public void unregister()
            {
                if(stage != null)
                {
                    focusOwnerListener.unregister();
                    stage.sceneProperty().removeListener(this);
                    stage = null;
                }
            }
        }

        private class FocusOwnerListener implements ChangeListener
        {
            private Scene scene;

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue aObservable, Node aOld, Node aNew)
            {
                focusedNodeProperty.set(aNew);
            }

            /**
             * @param aScene can be {@code null} in such case it is only an equivalent
             *           of {@link #unregister()}
             */
            public void register(Scene aScene)
            {
                if(scene != aScene)
                {
                    unregister();
                    scene = aScene;
                    focusedSceneProperty.set(aScene);
                    if(aScene != null)
                    {
                        focusedNodeProperty.set(aScene.getFocusOwner());
                        aScene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener(this);
                    }
                }
            }

            public void unregister()
            {
                if(scene != null)
                {
                    focusedSceneProperty.set(null);
                    focusedNodeProperty.set(null);
                    scene.focusOwnerProperty().removeListener(this);
                    scene = null;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```